# Replace NaN with 0 in my innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

When I click the button the variable "prod" writes NaN into my innerHTML. I need to replace NaN with 0 if the user has not selected any values. How would I add this function?

This is the script I'm using:

```
<script>
function  doMath() {
var one = eval(document.theForm.elements[0].value)
var two = eval(document.theForm.elements[1].value)
var three = eval(document.theForm.elements[2].value)
var prod = one * two * three
 d.innerHTML = "<p>" + "Your Customer’s Life Time Value is:" + "</p>" + "<p>" + "$" + prod + ".00" + "</p>";
 if (isNaN(doMath)) 
     return 0;
}
</script>
```

This is my HTML:

```
<form name="theForm">
<div>
    <div class="section-4-col-1">
        <div class="section-4-row-text">
            <p>Average Value of a Sale:<br><span style="font-size:12px;">(The average revenue of a single sale.)</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="section-4-row-input">
            <input placeholder="$" type="text" class="section-4-input">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-4-col-2">
        <div class="section-4-row-text">
            <p>Average Number of Sales Annually:<br><span style="font-size:12px;">(The average number of times that your customers make purchases from you on an annual basis.)</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="section-4-row-input">
            <!--<input placeholder="$" type="text" class="section-4-input">-->
            <select type="text" class="section-4-input">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
            <option>6</option>
            <option>7</option>
            <option>8</option>
            <option>9</option>
            <option>10</option>
            <option>11</option>
            <option>12</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-4-col-3">
        <div class="section-4-row-text">
            <p>Average Customer Retention (Years):<br><span style="font-size:12px;">(How long to your customers stay with you on average?)</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="section-4-row-input">
            <!--<input placeholder="$" type="text" class="section-4-input">-->
            <select type="text" class="section-4-input">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
            <option>6</option>
            <option>7</option>
            <option>8</option>
            <option>9</option>
            <option>10</option>
            <option>11</option>
            <option>12</option>
            <option>13</option>
            <option>14</option>
            <option>15</option>
            <option>16</option>
            <option>17</option>
            <option>18</option>
            <option>19</option>
            <option>20</option>
            <option>21</option>
            <option>22</option>
            <option>23</option>
            <option>24</option>
            <option>25</option>
            <option>26</option>
            <option>27</option>
            <option>28</option>
            <option>29</option>
            <option>30</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section-4-calculation-button">
    <p><button id="calcbutton" type="button" class="section-4-button" onClick="doMath()">Calculate My Score</button></p>
</div>
<div id="d" class="section-4-calculation-result">
    <p>Your Customer’s Life Time Value is:</p>
    <p>$0.00</p>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: You really want `parseInt(, 10)` or `Number()`, not `eval()`!

Comment: Why do you `return` from your function?

Comment: in addition to what Bergi said you can think about using `parseFloat(x, 10)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that decimal values are allowed, lose the `eval` calls!

```
var one = +document.theForm.elements[0].value || 0;
```

The `+` sign will attempt to convert the value to a number, and evaluates to `NaN` if the value is not a legal number.  The `|| 0` will convert `NaN` to zero, if found.

If only whole numbers are permitted, use `parseInt` instead of `+`, and always supply the radix parameter to ensure that leading zeroes don't lead to an inadvertent parsing as octal:

```
var one = parseInt(document.theForm.elements[0].value, 10) || 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function  doMath() { //No semicolons here...
var one = eval(document.theForm.elements[0].value) //Eval
var two = eval(document.theForm.elements[1].value)
var three = eval(document.theForm.elements[2].value)
var prod = one * two * three
 d.innerHTML = "<p>" + "Your Customer’s Life Time Value is:" + "</p>" + "<p>" + "$" + prod + ".00" + "</p>";
 if (isNaN(doMath)) //Use of innerHTML
     return 0;
}
```

Your code is seriously screwed up. Always use semicolons. Indent. Never use eval. Never use innerHTML.

```
function doMath() {
    var one = parseInt(document.theForm.elements[0].value, 10); //second argument is base
    var two = parseInt(document.theForm.elements[1].value, 10);
    var three = parseInt(document.theForm.elements[2].value, 10);
    var prod = one * two * three || 0; //Here
    d.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Your Customer’s Life Time Value is $' + prod)); //<p> tags are for paragraphs
    if (isNaN(doMath))
        return 0;
}
```

MDN: [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), [||](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR), [createTextNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTextNode), [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild).

Comment: 1. don't assume the values are integers, 2. if using `parseInt`, always supply the radix parameter!

Comment: While I'm on board with using semicolons as a style choice, you don't really *need* them due to ASI... you'll see many well-respected projects like Bootstrap eschew them.

Comment: @Alnitak From the output (with the `.00`), the inputs must be int. Edited.

Comment: @Spikolynn It's an unnatural form of DOM manipulation. Slow. Causes browser bugs. Loses event listeners.